# Ruby Scoping So Child Classes Of One Module See All Functions Of Another Module (Or Submodules)

Tags: ruby, class, module, scope

I'd like to have a module that contains a set of functions (in submodules?) that I can call from any (child) class in another module. How do I do this in Ruby?

Currently, I have something basic like the below. How do I call any function in the Policy namespace from the Services one (for example, at `???`)?

```rb
#/lib/services/base.rb
module Services
  class Base
  end
end
```

```rb
#/lib/services/child_service.rb
module Services
  class ChildService < Base

    def some_function()
      ???
    end
  end
end
```

and a second module called Policies that should just be a namespace for containing various functions (across multiple submodules to manage them practically):

```rb
#/lib/policies/policies.rb
module Policies
  extend self
end
```

```rb
#/lib/policies/subset_policies1.rb
module Policies::SubPolicies1
  extend self

  def does_exist?(arg)
  end
end
```

```rb
#/lib/policies/subset_policies2.rb
module Policies::SubPolicies2
  extend self

  def if_maybe?(arg)
  end
end
```

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your question. Can you clarify it? What do you mean by "function"? Ruby doesn't have functions, it has methods and blocks. The closest thing Ruby has to what is commonly referred to as "function" is a `Proc` object, but there are no `Proc`s in your code. Also, it is not clear what you mean by "namespace". That term is usually only used for constant lookup in Ruby. Same for the term "submodule". Modules *can* inherit from modules, but that is typically not called a "submodule". And lastly, the question is what you mean by "see".

Comment: Definitely a newbie! :) I guess instead of "submodule", I should have stated "nested module". And, by "functions" I guess I mean "methods". (I tend to associate the word "method" as being a function of a class only.)

Comment: As to "see", how do I get the body of ChildService.some_function to be able to call/use Policies::SubPolicies2.if_maybe?